# How to filter text within a certain area using pdfPlumber and open CV?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfplumber

I've got a bunch of pdf files which are from conference proceedings.
Every pdf file's structure looks like:

> ```
>                    Tile with bold, large size font
>     Author1                Author2                 AuthorN
> Afflication1          Afflication2            AfflicationN
> Email1                  Email2                   Email3
> ```

I used pdfPlumber to choose the chars with largest font size as the title, it works.
And to get the author - affliation - Email information,
I use cv2 to indentify text blocks and then to filter the chars within each cv2's box.
But right now it does not work.
Iit seems that the boxpoints's x/y (generated by cv2) is not the same as the x0/x1/top/bottom generated by pdfPlumber.

Here is how I did it. Any help or comment will be appreciated.

```py
def getCharsInBox(box):
    left_point_x=np.min(box[:,0])
    right_point_x=np.max(box[:,0])
    top_point_y=np.min(box[:,1])
    bottom_point_y=np.max(box[:,1])
    return lambda x:((x.get("x0",0)>=left_point_x &\
                      x.get("x0",0)<=right_point_x &\
                      x.get("top",0)>=top_point_x &\
                      x.get("bottom",0)<=bottom_point_y))


for box in region:
    filtered=page.filter(getCharsInBox(box))
    pdfAAE=filtered.extract_text()
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
In pdfPlumber, the unit of x0/x1/y0/y1,... is **point**, actual 1/72 inch. This is from pdf standard.
While in opencv, the "unit" is **pixel**.
So **pixel** needs to converted into **point** before carrying out filtering.

Another worthy noticed point is that, even after corping, the coordination of each char in page object (pdfPlumper) still based on the orginal page. So one has to substract the copped x/y corrdination for these filtering, like below:

```py
def getCharsInBox(box):
    # img.shape=[width of img, heigh of image,other]
    left_point_x=np.min(box[:,0])*page.width/img.shape[1]
    right_point_x=np.max(box[:,0])*page.width/img.shape[1]
    top_point_y=np.min(box[:,1])*page.height/img.shape[0]
    bottom_point_y=np.max(box[:,1])*page.height/img.shape[0]
    return lambda x:((x.get("x0",0)>=left_point_x &\
                      x.get("x0",0)<=right_point_x &\
                      x.get("top",0)-croppedY>=top_point_x &\
                      x.get("bottom",0)-croppedY<=bottom_point_y))


for box in region:
    filtered=page.filter(getCharsInBox(box))
    pdfAAE=filtered.extract_text()
```